# How do I implement server sent event in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, server-sent-events

I want to make a real time application with CI.
So I write some code in controller (CI)

Here's my code:

```
  $this->output->set_content_type('text/event-stream');
  $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  $time = date('r');
  $output="data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
  flush();
```

But, I get this error:

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not
>   "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the content type:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('text/plain', 'UTF-8');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate')
```

Please read the [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Codeigniter 3, you have to change:

```
set_output => _display 

$time = date('r');
$output="data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
$this->output->set_content_type('text/event-stream')->_display($output);
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
flush();
```

see example

Answer (score 0):

from codeigniter docs:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html

**$this->output->set_content_type();**

Permits you to set the mime-type of your page so you can serve JSON data, JPEG's, XML, etc easily.

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));

$this->output->set_content_type('jpeg') // You could also use ".jpeg" which will have the full stop removed before looking in config/mimes.php
    ->set_output(file_get_contents('files/something.jpg'));
```

Important: Make sure any non-mime string you pass to this method exists in config/mimes.php or it will have no effect.

**Second Option**

Go to your `application/config/mimes.php`
add `'txt'  =>  'text/event-stream',`
to `$mimes` array.

**EDIT**
change your code to:

```
    $time = date('r');
    $output="data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    $this->output->set_content_type('text/event-stream')->set_output($output);
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    flush();
```

Comment: I also changed in mimes.php. But I can't slove this error. Thank Imram Qamer.

Comment: yes you changed mime tipes but u did not add output function call as set_output($output), check my modifies answer